# How to regenerate a google-services.json and revoke the old one without affecting production

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform

This question is about `google-services.json` which can be generated by creating firebase apps. This question is not about google service accounts, just about `google-services.json`

We're using Flutter. Our Android and IOS apps are in production, we have many users. The `google-services.json` has been committed to git. Some people shouldn't have access to it.

We want to create a new `google-services.json` and revoke the existing one

If we try to create a Firebase application with the same identifier as our android application. `com.bar.foo`, we'll get an error saying that the package identifier has already been used.

We can't revoke the existing application which has been compromised before making sure that our users have updated the app and started using a new version with the new firebase app.

So what to do in this case? How can we create a new Firebase app, generate a new `google-services.json` and then revoke the existing one afterward?

Comment: Just making sure you've read the section on [separate keys for specific APIs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys?authuser=0#use-separate-keys-for-specific-apis) and the [Firebase FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/api-keys?authuser=0#faqs)

Comment: @MorrisonChang This is a good read, thank you for sharing but this doesn't address my question, these are recommended practices which I need to follow after fixing the problem at hand

Comment: I think the question is what is connected to your `google-services.json` and what is your threat model given that `Although API keys used for Firebase services do not generally need to be treated as secret` since on each platform you have the identifier `com.bar.foo`.